# Add custom object to Cognos 10 Toolbox

Tags: xml, cognos, cognos-bi

I wanted to add a custom object into the Cognos Toolbox (in Report Studio).

The object I want to create is a table that has a background and be able to drag this object into the report and insert any other type of object like textbox, dateprompt, etc...

I know I'll need to update the toolbox.html but what/where is the actual xml file that stores the attributes of the objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you use layout components reference for applying common object formatting patterns. A good approach is to create a single report with reusable layout components and reference them in reports. Therefore all changes in the layout components report will propagate to all linked ones. 
Some links on the topic:

- [Report studio user guide](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cbi/v10r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.swg.im.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.10.1.0.doc%2Fug_cr_rptstd_id23749cr_rptstd_frmat_rep_reuse_object.html)
- [Ironside blog post](http://www.ironsidegroup.com/2010/07/08/designing-effective-ibm-cognos-report-studio-templates/)

Changing toolbox.html will cause you grief with future upgrades.

Another option would be to use Report classes for applying formatting, they can also be centrally changed.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with ykud - use a central report with formatting and reference it.

Alternatively here is a guide for custom toolbox objects in version 8.3

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/cognos/page294.html

This indicates that you need to add your custom control definition to ToolboxControls.XML found in ..\c8\webcontent\pat\res

It has good workshop on doing exactly what you need.